# Export to csv after printing table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, csv

Been trying to figure this out since a hell of a lot of hours, but without result. A user can select some filters in a form, which result in a unique table, printed to the screen.

Then I want a button to export this specific table to a csv file, stored on the users computer.

```
if(isset($_POST["askReport"])){ 
//all the variables
//...
$myQuery = ""SELECT *, TIME_TO_SEC(stopwerkdagU) - TIME_TO_SEC(startwerkdagU) - pauzetijdU AS totaalurenU, TIME_TO_SEC(stopwerkdagU) - TIME_TO_SEC(startwerkdag) - pauzetijd AS totaaluren FROM `newRegister` $u $aP $pD $uF $sD"";

$result = $mysqli->query($myQuery);
  if($result->num_rows >0){
    print '<table><tr><th>.....'; //and all the headers
    print '<td>'.$row["user"].'</td>';
    ..... //and all the other columns and end of row
  }
```

So far, so good, I get a nice table with the results that I want. But then comes the tricky part - how do I get the button to download this table? Here's what I tried: (this code is stil in the isset($_POST["askReport"]) if statement)

```
// DOWNLOAD TABEL
    print '<form method="POST"><button name=download>download</button></form>';

    if(isset($_POST["download"])){
        $select = "SELECT *, TIME_TO_SEC(stopwerkdagU) - TIME_TO_SEC(startwerkdagU) - pauzetijdU AS totaalurenU, TIME_TO_SEC(stopwerkdagU) - TIME_TO_SEC(startwerkdag) - pauzetijd AS totaaluren FROM `newRegister` $u $aP $pD $uF $sD";

        $export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

        $fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

        for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
        {
            $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
        }

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
        {
            $line = '';
            foreach( $row as $value )
            {                                            
                if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
                {
                    $value = "\t";
                }
                else
                {
                    $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                }
                $line .= $value;
            }
            $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
        }
        $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

        if ( $data == "" )
        {
            $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
        }

        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download  .xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        print "$header\n$data";         
    };

}
```

This doesn't give any errors. It just reloads the page. So I can't figure out why it isn't working. I thank you for your help.

Comment: Which browser are you testing on?

Comment: Everything works fine for me. Tested on Safari 8.0

Comment: Stop using your homebrew CSV code, and use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function

Comment: And why are you generating csv data to send to the browser while also sending printed output containing html markup to the browser?

Comment: I'm testing on Safari 8.0.1

Comment: @MarkBaker: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean - can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: I mean you have `print '<form method="POST"><button name=download>download</button></form>';` at the top of your script, but then you're outputting tab-separated value data, and using headers to claim that it's an xls file, when in actuality it's not an xls file, and neither a csv nor html because it's a mish-mash of both

Comment: That top line print statement will also give you a "headers already sent" waring, if you have errors fully enabled (as you should in a development environment)

Comment: How should I trigger the script, then? BTW, thanks for the header info, changed it to
header('Content-type: text/csv');header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=download.csv');

Comment: Only print the form if `$_POST["download"]` is __not__ set

Answer (score 0):

PARTIAL SOLUTION

The following code (your code, just with the MySQL commented out for testing purposes) works fine. I'm running Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.14

The thing that made the downloading work was when I put the `<?php` and `?>` tags in. Try this code and let me know if it works.

```
<?php
// DOWNLOAD TABEL
    print '<form method="POST"><button name=download>download</button></form>';

    if(isset($_POST["download"])){
        $select = "SELECT *, TIME_TO_SEC(stopwerkdagU) - TIME_TO_SEC(startwerkdagU) - pauzetijdU AS totaalurenU, TIME_TO_SEC(stopwerkdagU) - TIME_TO_SEC(startwerkdag) - pauzetijd AS totaaluren FROM `newRegister` $u $aP $pD $uF $sD";

/*        $export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

        $fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

        for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
        {
            $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
        }

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
        {
            $line = '';
            foreach( $row as $value )
            {   
                if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
                {
                    $value = "\t";
                }
                else
                {
                    $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                    $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
                }
                $line .= $value;
            }
            $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
        }
        $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );
*/

        if ( $data == "" )
        {
            $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";
        }

$header="abc,123";

        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download  .xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        echo "$header\n$data";
    };

?>
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Using safari 8.0.1. Thanks.